# VS2015-CTP: Unable to get Ripple session info. Exception: Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

i recently installed the new windows 10 preview and the visual studio 2015-ctp (complete installation) and tried to play with cordova. So i just created a new project from the templates and tried to run it with ripple.

I got an error message pointing out that ANDROID_HOME is not defined, so i added a new environment variable:

ANDROID_HOME pointing to: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

Now i got another error without any hints on how to deal with it:

Unable to get launched browser process for Ripple.
Unable to get Ripple session info. Exception: Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.

Any ideas? 
Thanks very much!

Edit: Still no answer? Do you have problems understanding my Question?

Answer (score 0):

In VS, go to Tools > Options > Tools for Apache Cordova > Environment Variable Overrides. You might try setting the Android SDK variable here. It may report errors if there's a problem.